# Error when using numpy module in Sublime Text

Tags: python, numpy, sublimetext3

I am trying to set up and use numpy on sublime text. However, it marks the numpy instructions as syntax errors.

If I type out something simple like below ,

```
import numpy as np
print np.pi,np.e
x= np.random.random(10)
print(x)
```

Running this file from the terminal works fine and I get the desired result as -

Dabbling with Python  python `Linear-Regression.py`

```
3.14159265359 2.71828182846
[ 0.89299598  0.95393114  0.52340898  0.93117159  0.71658433  0.62331653
  0.60741025  0.92175348  0.99218785  0.94231719]
```

However, on sublime text I get errors on lines 2 and warnings on all other lines.

**Error - Module 'numpy' has no 'pi' member; Module 'numpy' has no 'e' member.**

I have installed plugin anaconda and pylinter

Comment: you are using window or linux dev?

Comment: seems like sublime doesn't understand where is numpy file...have you installed globally on your mac??

Answer (score 0):

Check which python version is being called when you run your script from the command line and copy the path, i.e. `which python`.  Edit your `Python.sublime-build` file:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "python -u \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

and replace `python` on the first line with the path you just copied.

Comment: This didnt help. I started using pyCharm instead.